# Binary Search through multiple elements

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search

I had this question on an exam,

I have a very slow computer which takes one second for binary search on an array with 1,000 (one thousand) elements.  How long should I expect the computer to take for binary search on an array with 1,000,000 (one million) elements?

I have trouble understanding this, would it take longer to search through 1 million elements than 1,000 or does it depend on the computer?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://cs.stackexchange.com and does not actually relate to any specific programming language. Anyway, you probably should ask your instructor about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary search has `O(log(N))` time complexity, completion time is

```
t = c * log(N, 10)
```

In given case for `N = 1000` we know `t` and thus we can find out `c`

```
1 = c * log(1000, 10) 

1 = c * 3

c = 1/3
```

For `N = 1000000` we have

```
t = 1 / 3 * log(1000000, N) =
  = 1 / 3 * 6 = 
  = 2
```

So we can expect that binary search within `1000000` items will be completed in **2** seconds.

Please, note that `O(log(N)) == O(log(N, m))` since `log(N, m) == log(N, k) / log(m, k)`, which means that when working with `O(log(N))` we are free to choose logarithm base. In our case (`1000` and `1000000`) it's convenient to use base `10` (or `1000`)

Answer (score 1):

First, a binary search requires the list or array to be sorted.  And since you are dividing each list/sublist in half it will take `log2(N)` searches to find the correct item where `log2` is log to the `base 2`.

So for `1_000_000` items it should only take about `20 comparisons` to home in on the item.  So it should be very quick (sans the time to sort the list to begin with).

`1000` items would take about `10 comparisons`.  And one second, imo, is much to long to do such a simple search on any modern day processor.

Answer (score 0):

It does depend on the computer and also depends on the size of the array. Since in this question the same computer is used, we can abstract the effects of the computer and focus on the sample size.

Binary search has logarithmic [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity). If you take the difference between log(1_000) and log(1_000_000) you will see that you should expect double the time (2 seconds) to search in the 1 million elements array.

This is assuming worst case. For the average case, the calculation gets more complex, you can check [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) for a deeper analysis.